# Environment variables not available in websocket

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty, java-websocket

I want to access an environment variable, defined in the web.xml, in an instance of a javax WebSocket, running with jetty9.

I can access the environment variable in any servlet, or the `onOpen` method of the WebSocket, but not in the `onMessage` method of the WebSocket

web.xml :

```xml
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>entry</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>env value</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

WebSocket.java :

```java
package com.example;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;

@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class WebSocket {

    public String getEntry(Session session) {
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            return (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/entry");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        String entry = getEntry(session);
        System.out.println("onOpen: entry = " + (entry != null ? entry : "Not found"));
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        String entry = getEntry(session);
        System.out.println("onMessage: entry = " + (entry != null ? entry : "Not found"));
    }

}
```

pom.xml :

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webAppDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Output:

```
onOpen: entry = env value
onMessage: entry = Not found
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/entry'
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:108)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.example.WebSocket.getEntry(WebSocket.java:17)
    at com.example.WebSocket.onMessage(WebSocket.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.CallableMethod.call(CallableMethod.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.annotations.OnMessageTextCallable.call(OnMessageTextCallable.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.annotations.JsrEvents.callText(JsrEvents.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.endpoints.JsrAnnotatedEventDriver.onTextMessage(JsrAnnotatedEventDriver.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.endpoints.JsrAnnotatedEventDriver.onTextFrame(JsrAnnotatedEventDriver.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.readParse(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to add a custom ServletContextListener :

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "config";
    private String entry;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
        String entryName = servletContext.getInitParameter("entry");
        try {
            entry = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/entry");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Config failed: entry not found", e);
        }
        servletContext.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }

    public String getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public static Config getInstance(ServletContext servletContext) {
        return (Config) servletContext.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    }
}
```

On connection acceptance, the method onOpen write a new context, you can simply pass ServletContext by adding it into an [EndpointConfig](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/EndpointConfig.html) map for the current context

```
public class ServletSavingContext extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
        config.getUserProperties().put("context", httpSession.getServletContext());
    }

}
```

Now in your previous class :

```
package com.example;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws", configurator = ServletSavingContext.class)
public class WebSocket {

  private EndpointConfig config;

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) throws IOException {
    this.config = config;
    String entry = Config.getInstance(config.getUserProperties("context")).getEntry();
    System.out.println("onOpen: entry = " + (entry != null ? entry : "Not found"));
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
    String entry = Config.getInstance(config.getUserProperties("context")).getEntry();
    System.out.println("onMessage: entry = " + (entry != null ? entry : "Not found"));
  }
}
```

Some documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/EndpointConfig.html#getUserProperties%28%29

Comment: Thank's but this is not what I asked. I need to have the entry in the Initial context.

Comment: Edited to maybe sweets your needs

Comment: Sorry, but that still not answer my question. I need to be able of retrieving the variable from the `InitialContext` object itself, anywhere in the code: `new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/entry")`

Answer (score 0):

*Note: The following is probably not "best practice" and may not be guaranteed to work on all containers, but works for me on Tomcat, and may be of use to others?*

You can assign the context to an instance variable in `onOpen`, and then use that same instance variable in `onMessage`.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class WebSocket {

    private Context envContext;

    public String getEntry(Session session) {
        try {
            return this.envContext.lookup("entry");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            this.envContext = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        String entry = getEntry(session);
        System.out.println("onOpen: entry = " + (entry != null ? entry : "Not found"));
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        String entry = getEntry(session);
        System.out.println("onMessage: entry = " + (entry != null ? entry : "Not found"));
    }

}
```

Comment: @BalusC when the websocket receives a connection a new instance of the WebSocket is created, and it is only used in a single thread I believe?  So there won't be concurrent calls to onOpen or OnMessage?  So the Context object won't be accessed concurrently?

Answer (score -2):

Here is a workaround. I simply populate the context with the variable stored earlier:

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException, NamingException {
    // Somewhere after onOpen, populate the context
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    ctx.createSubcontext("java:comp/env");
    ctx.bind("java:comp/env/entry", STORED_ENTRY);  // Store the variable as an attribute of the WebSocket

    String entry = getEntry(session);
    System.out.println("onMessage: entry = " + (entry != null ? entry : "Not found")); 
}
```

Comment: JNDI is part of the JEE/HTTP/Servlet specs.  Once you transition away from HTTP spec via the HTTP Upgrade (to WebSocket in your case) everything related to HTTP (including the Servlet spec) no longer applies.  The only safe way to do this is to obtain the reference BEFORE you transition, in a `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.modifyHandshake()` for example, and use it within your WebSocket endpoint.